# How to change other components' property with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using `styled-components` and I am trying to change the height of `Top` to `300px` when I focus on my `Input`.

I was tried something like this but not working:

```
&:focus ${Top} {
  height: 500px;
}
```

Dom Structure:

```
<Top>
    <Avatar
            src="./assets/person/1.jpeg"
            alt=""
            sx={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }}
      />
      <Input placeholder="What's in your mind?" />
</Top>
```

My code:

```
export const Top = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 150px;
`;

export const Input = styled.textarea`
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;

  &:focus ${Top} {
    height: 500px;
  }
`;
```

How do I change other components' prop with styled-components?

Answer (score 0):

Use `~` selector:

```js
export const Top = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 150px;
`;

export const Input = styled.textarea`
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;

  &:focus ~ ${Top} {
    height: 500px;
  }
`;
```

What's your dom structure?

Comment: It is not working. I updated my post for the dom structure.

Comment: Eh, the dom structure looks can't use css to implement. You need use JavaScript's focus event.